# Proving continuity of the Lebesgue integral with the Monotone Convergence Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I'm trying to prove the following claim: Let $f$ be a nonnegative measurable function. We define $F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x {f(u)du}$. Show that $F$ is continuous by using the Monotone Convergence Theorem.

I started by writing the integral as:

$$F(x_0)=\int_{-\infty}^{x_0}{f(u)du} = \int{f(u)\cdot \chi_{(-\infty,x_0)}(u)du}$$

and tried to prove the claim using Heine's criterion: $F(x)$ is continuous at $x_0$ if and only if for each sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ such that $x_n\rightarrow x_0$, $F(x_n)\rightarrow F(x_0)$.

I've managed to prove this for monotone sequences, i.e. $x_n\uparrow x_0$ and $x_n\downarrow x_0$, using the Monotone Convergence Theorem, however I got stuck when trying to prove this for a general sequence.

Comment: It's OK just to prove left-continuity and right-continuity, so you can assume all $x_n<x_0$ or all $x_n>0$. In the case where all $x_n<x_0$, why not consider $y_n=\max(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$?

Comment: With your hypothesis $F$ need not be real valued.  Do you want to assume that $f$ is integrable?

Comment: I understand why looking only at left-continuity and right-continuity helps, however I don't quite see how looking at $y_n=\max(x_1,...,x_n)$ helps. I'm looking at $\int_{-\infty}^{x_n}{f(u)du}$, how does one relate this sequence to $\int_{-\infty}^{y_n}{f(u)du}$?

Comment: The idea is that $f\chi_{[-\infty,x_n]}$ converges monotonically to $f\chi_{[-\infty,x_0]}$ if $x_n\to x_0$ monotonically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $f$ just non-negative and measurable the monotone convergence theorem for decreasing sequences doesn't hold in general, for this case we will need to assume other hypothesis, by example that $f$ is essentially bounded or that is dominated for an integrable function.

Assuming that the monotone convergence theorem holds for decreasing sequences then you can use the limit superior and limit inferior of a real-valued sequence to show the convergence for an arbitrary convergent sequence $(x_n)$, that is, if $\lim_{n\to \infty }x_n=x_0$ then 
$$
\begin{align*}
\limsup_{n\to \infty }x_n=\lim_{n\to \infty }\sup_{k\geqslant n}x_n=x_0\tag1\\
\liminf_{n\to \infty }x_n=\lim_{n\to \infty }\inf_{k\geqslant n}x_n=x_0\tag2
\end{align*}
$$
Now setting $s_n:=\sup_{k\geqslant n}x_n$ and $i_n:=\inf_{k\geqslant n}x_n$ we have that $(s_n)\downarrow x_0$ and $(i_n)\uparrow x_0$ and that $i_n\leqslant x_n\leqslant s_n$ for all $n\in \Bbb N $, hence
$$
\int_{-\infty }^{i_n}f(u)\,\mathrm d u\leqslant \int _{-\infty }^{x_n}f(u)\,\mathrm d u\leqslant \int_{-\infty }^{s_n}f(u)\,\mathrm d u\tag3
$$
Then taking limits in $\rm(3)$ you are done.